# how to control the depth (z index) of bordercontainer in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, z-index, depth

i'm desperately trying to set my border container the highest z-index so it will always appear on top.

how can I know how many objects are in my flex stage, so i'll be able to set the bordercontainer the highest depth?
what shell i write in the depth property in order the border container would always be on top? (it's important to mention that i created dynamic objects)

```
    <s:BorderContainer includeIn="state2" width="200" height="200" backgroundColor="#992F2F"
                   horizontalCenter="-61" verticalCenter="23" depth.state2=currentState.num>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the depth param

```
   <s:BorderContainer includeIn="state2" width="200" height="200" backgroundColor="#992F2F"
               horizontalCenter="-61" verticalCenter="23" **depth=999** >
   </s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: hey, that didn't work - i tried to write high numbers but nothing happened.. how ever it worked when i simply added id to the bordercontainer ("muBorderContainer") and then wrote:      addElement(muBorderContainer);